# Power adapters logos

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

Is there a list with the logos which appear on some power adapters?

I have two adapters and I'm wondering which one is better for my application. I'm interested especially on the output EMI filtering.

The adapters are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMq5E.jpg). One is China made by Creative and one is made in Germany (I couldn't identify the producer). My question is which of the two adapters has a better quality, judging only by the logos on them?

[image: adapter]
[image: adapter2]

Comment: Without even seeing them - the german one will be better quality.

Comment: Thanks. The german one is even repairable (it has screws on it).

Comment: @JohnU As someone who buys parts from germany and china, that is not always true :) The fact you can repair the part easily is probably a sign of a good design.

Comment: @Kortuk - sweeping generalisations are **never** right. But I wouldn't bet money against the German one ;)

Comment: German one is missing FCC designation.  If you intend to sell your system in the US, you must use the Chinese one.  The Chinese one also is branded for Creative Labs and has a manufacturer name prominently displayed (Technics) whereas the German one looks like more of a knock off.  Chinese one also has a greater power rating than the German one.  I'd choose the Chinese supply.

Comment: Well this is true only if the label is genuine. I've taken apart the german one. You can find pictures [here](http://imgur.com/97RdK7c), it uses [rfp14N05](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/fairchild/RFP14N05.pdf) as N-Channel Power MOSFET. Does FCC implies something about EMI filtering?

Comment: The german one is linear and the chinese is switched. I'll stick with the linear one, probably less noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of Power Adaptor Compliance Symbols and their meanings. It's not all inclusive: [Standard Certification Marks](http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_safetymarks)

The Chinese one is manufactured for Creative, a big US based electronics producer (Creative Zen mp3 player), **if** the label isn't fake. It is universal 100 to 240 Volts 50/60 Hz, so works in the US and overseas in most cases, with a simple outlet adaptor. It provides up to 1.5 Amps at 5v with a center positive barrel jack.

The german one is generic (No manufacturer labeling or manufactured for), is 230 Volts 50 Hz, so will not work in the U.S. (or other places with 110/60Hz) without a transformer. It only provides 1 Amp at 5v, no labeling to pinout.

FCC approval means that the FCC in the US has tested it and found it produces only a reasonable amount of RF/EMI under very strict conditions, and shouldn't interfere with other electronics around it. Again, this only counts if the label isn't fake, which is a common occurrence.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't know what the B in a reversed triangle means, but your answer is to the point.

Comment: I think the B is a [voluntary safety mark](http://www.iecee.org/cbscheme/NCB/Information/PL-PCBC.htm) meant for Poland:

Comment: @passerby the second seems to have a CE mark, which actually has more thorough testing requirements then FCC, last I checked, they either go lower or higher frequency, I often forget.

Comment: @Kortuk CE testing is voluntary and often is done without formal checks (unless something fails). It's almost a meaningless mark since it's so poorly enforced.

Comment: Are you sure? Google "ce mark vs china export" to see, because that could just be "China Export" instead. BOTH have them. @Kortuk

Comment: @Passerby [I think that is it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CE_marking).

Comment: @Madmanguruman They do not require you provide evidence of the testing unless someone complains that it was violating the standard, to my knowledge. In that case you need to have evidence. This may be very poorly enforced, but it is technically the case, they may or may not have performed that testing.

Comment: @Kortuk Those are legit CE euro marks. The China Export mark has the C and E closer together. The Euro mark spaces the E such that if you complete the inner circle of the C, it just touches the E. And Kortuk, that "produce evidence only if infringement is suspected" idea is why many companies just slap the mark on the product and worry about evidence later (or not at all).

Comment: @Madmanguruman Yes, I thought that might be what you meant. Requires a complaint is a bit light, but I have never made a product in the EU nor do I really know how people operate there. Interesting information.

Answer (score 2):

Quality is wildly subjective, and cannot be discerned by the number of safety marks on a device. Safety marks mean a device will fail safely, not that it will perform indefinitely.

The Creative one is capable of "universal input" (100-240VAC) and has North American (UL + ULC) and European (TUV / Geprüfte Sicherheit) marks. The B mark is for Poland (a voluntary mark) and the big S / Safety Mark is for Singapore. The double square means that the device has reinforced insulation.

The German one has a VDE Geprüfte Sicherheit mark for Europe, as well as a bunch of other European marks (D for Denmark, N for Norway, S for Sweden, FI for Finland, S+ for Switzerland, KEMA-KUR is a DEKRA mark, CEBEC is Belgium, etc.)

Again, which is "better"? You tell us.

Comment: Well the german one is linear but it is using a zener (and two transistors) for the voltage regulator -- kind of outdated. Because it is linear, I suppose it is quitter as well (I don't have access to an oscilloscope). From the stand point of EMI still the linear is better, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply#SMPS_and_linear_power_supply_comparison)

Comment: Again, totally subjective. The switcher will have good enough EMI to not cause unnecessary interference, and will be much more efficient. Better is in the eye of the beholder.